# Group rings of free abelian groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, group-rings

Is it true that for free abelian finitely generated groups $G_1$ and $G_2$, if $\mathbb Z[G_1]\simeq \mathbb Z[G_2]$, then $G_1\simeq G_2$? If yes, is there any reference to such a fact?

Comment: I don't know a reference, but can count $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}[G],\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Hopefully this earlier answer is helpful: https://mathoverflow.net/a/299923/

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA I think you want to count homomorphisms to $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ rather than to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. For any $G$ there's only one ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[G]\to\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It is corollary 3 here https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-136-00/S0002-9947-1969-0233903-9/S0002-9947-1969-0233903-9.pdf

Comment: Sorry, for free abelian this is easier but it is true for any abelian groups.  Free abelian groups are left orderable and so satisfy the Kaplansky unit conjecture.  You can find in Passman's group ring book that if $G_1$ satisfies the Kaplansky unit conjecture and $\mathbb ZG_1\cong \mathbb ZH$ then $G_1\cong H$.

Comment: The Krull dimension of $\mathbf{Z}[\mathbf{Z}^d]$ is $d+1$. And also for every torsion-free abelian group $G$, the group of units of $\mathbf{Z}[G]/2\mathbf{Z}[G]$ is reduced to $G$ (as mentioned by Benjamin Steinberg, this extends to the case when $G$ is left-orderable).

Answer (score 10):

This is true for any abelian groups (finitely generated and free abelian is not needed); see Corollary 3 of [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-136-00/S0002-9947-1969-0233903-9/S0002-9947-1969-0233903-9.pdf).  Basically, if $\mathbb ZG_1\cong \mathbb ZG_2$, then $H_n(G_1,\mathbb Z)\cong H_n(G_2,\mathbb Z)$ for all $n\geq 0$ and since $H_1$ gives the abelianization, this gives the desired result.  In fact, isomorphism of group rings implies isomorphism of abelianization.  For free abelian groups, this has many elementary proofs.  The easiest to me is that Laurent polynomial rings have only trivial units (multiples of group elements) by looking at highest and lowest degree terms in a unit times its inverse and it is easy to prove that if a group ring $\mathbb ZG$ has only trivial units then $G$ is recovered as $(\mathbb ZG)^{\times}/\mathbb Z^\times$.

The key idea for the homology approach  is to show that every isomorphism of groups rings can be replaced by one which preserves augmentation.  It suffices to show that if $\omega\colon \mathbb ZG\to\mathbb Z$ is the augmentation map and $\alpha\colon \mathbb ZG\to \mathbb Z$ is any ring homomorphism then there is an automorphism $\sigma$ of $\mathbb ZG$ with $\alpha\sigma=\omega$.  But $\alpha(g)\in \mathbb Z^\times$ and so $\sigma(g) = \alpha(g)^{-1}g$ is the desired automorphism.